# Why is my ZFS pool spending 97% of its time reading the target and only about 3% writing, on a write operation?

Tags: performance, zfs, freenas, performance-monitor, performance-tuning

This perplexes me and I don't know a way to drill down into what ZFS is actually doing.

I'm using a clean install of FreeNAS 11.1 with a fast ZFS  pool (imported mirrors on fast 7200s) plus a solitary UFS SSD for testing. Config is pretty much "out of the box".

The SSD contains 4 files of sizes 16 -120 GB, copied using console to the pool. The pool is deduped (worth it: 4x saving, 12TB size on disk) and the system has plenty of RAM (128GB ECC) and fast Xeon. Memory is plenty adequate - `zdb` shows the pool has a total of 121M blocks (544 bytes each on disk, 175 bytes each in RAM) so the entire DDT is only about 20.3 GB (about 1.7 GB per TB of data).

But when I copy the files to the pool, I see this in `zpool iostat`:
[image]

Its doing a cycle of as much as a minute of low level reads, and a brief burst of writes. The read part is shown in the pic. The overall  write speed for the task isn't great either  - the pool is 45%/10TB empty and natively can write at around 300 - 500 MB/s.

Without knowing how to check, my suspicion is that the low level reads are from reading the DDT and other metadata, as they aren't preloaded into ARC (or are continually being pushed out from ARC by file data being written).  Maybe.

Maybe its finding dedup hits so there isn't much writing, only I don't recall any dup versions of these files and it does the same from /dev/random as best I recall (I'll check this and update shortly). Maybe. No real idea.

What can I do to dig into what's going on more exactly, with a view to optimising it?

**Update on RAM and dedup:**

I've updated the Q to show DDT size following the initial comment. Dedup RAM is often quoted as 5GB per TB x 4, but that's based on an example that's really not very suitable for dedup. You have to calculate the block count multiplied by bytes per entry. The "x 4" often quoted is just a "soft" default limit only (by default ZFS limits metadata to 25% of ARC unless told to use more - this system is specced for dedup and I added 64GB which is **all** usable to speed up metadata caching).

So in this pool `zdb` confirms the entire DDT should need only 1.7 GB per TB not 5GB per TB (20G total), and I'm happy to give metadata 70% of ARC not 25% (80G out of 123G).

At that size it shouldn't need to eject *anything* other than 'dead' file contents from ARC.   So I'm looking to actually probe ZFS to find what it thinks is going on, and so I can see the effect of any changes I make, because I really am very surprised at its huge "low level reads" amount, and looking for a way to probe and confirm the reality of what it thinks its doing.

Comment: It's deduplication.  From the rules of thumb in the article [ZFS: To Dedupe or not to Dedupe...](https://constantin.glez.de/2011/07/27/zfs-to-dedupe-or-not-dedupe/), you may need some 240GiB of RAM (12TiB × 5GiB/TiB × 4) to fit the whole dedup table in there.  That article is probably more useful than an answer I could write here.

Comment: Thanks and Q updated. Im more looking for ways to actually probe it. I too can't think what else it can be - except it shouldn't be. The dedup table in the online examples is from a pool without much duplication. Mine is 4x and that means the entire DDT is only 1.7GB per TB or 20GB, under 17% of ARC (see update for calc). In theory I'm nowhere near any such limit and dedup should be 100% in RAM (or tunable to be so). Hence my perplexity at its activity and interest in probing ZFS to learn exactly what **it** thinks its actually doing.......

Comment: How about testing the same data inside a new pool without dedup? Then afterwards a smaller amount of data with dedup, but according to the rule Deltik posted. That way, you can reduce the unknown factors pretty quickly.

Comment: @user121391 in a CoW filesystem comparing against a new, fresh filesystem is not reducing the unknowns so much. it is good for finding out what the baseline could be, but other factors also matter (i.e. if the fs was ever completely full). Seeing that the disks are of uneven sizes etc. I nonetheless agree that this system is probably better off not running dedup :)